# Do any languages regularly derive their words for males from words for females?

Tags: list-of-languages, affixes, natural-gender

Specifically, I am looking for languages that derive the equivalent word for males from the word for females using some sort of masculine affix. Also, to be clear, they should be words for people, not just grammatical gender.

For context, in English, there is a dearth of such words, but the opposite category, female words derived from male words, has plenty of examples (e.g., actor to actress, bachelor to bachelorette, fiancé to fiancée). Some of these words come from other (Romance) languages, where it's also very common to add a feminine suffix. I [looked for any and all male words derived from female words](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/421783/191178) in English and came up with only this list:

- Bridegroom
- Widower
- Man-[noun]/male [noun] ("man crone", "male nurse")

*Bridegroom* is the only example of a masculine affix (though it has been lost to time), since "er" is not masculine, and the others aren't quite affixes.

The question [In romance languages, are there examples of male names that derive from female names?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/28566/22150) was interesting, but I'm not looking for personal names.

Comment: The ‘suffix’ in _bridegroom_ is historically a noun meaning ‘man’, so essentially the same as _-man_ tacked on to another word (as in _chairman_, etc.). To the extent that that counts as an ‘affix’, it’s not really so very different from _man-_ used before the head (_manwhore_, etc.).

Comment: Suppose *weaving* was primarily a female occupation, then *weaver* would be female derived without giving it away (but this example may be bogus). A clear case of zero-derivation is *slut* especially in gay lingo, which behaves no different than *nurse* without the "male" prefix because English has long lost canonical marking of gender. Whether *sonabitch* or *bitch* was first may debatable (compare *\*abuhaz*; I'm tempted to say the etymology is *opaque*).

Comment: @vectory "Man-slut" is one of the terms I mentioned in the other Q&A and I don't see the relevance of "weaver". I'm not looking for "zero-derivation"; there must be a female and a male form. As for "son of a bitch", that's neither a regular formation in English (we have only "son of a gun"), nor a real synonym for "bitch".

Comment: but *man-sut* is zero derivation in the synthetic sense. It's not *man-slut-[ending]* and man is a simple noun in attributive usage, no different from, say, *rain coat*, *male coat, female coat*. "Slut" is not *grammatically* coded feminine, nor is *nurse*, *coat* or *skirt*. So your question requires implicit assumptions about what it means to be female, which isn't terribly well defined. What you mean to ask is something about the closed class of determiners, I suppose. Otherwise, try as king your question in more technical terms without reference to English, because it contradicts the title

Comment: [cont.] since what I understand it to mean is the opposite of German where a) *Pfleger* is assumed to be male or underspecified and *-in* marks it specifically feminine b) *Schwester* "nurse, sister" does not admit a masculine derivation where preference for *Pfleger* is widely accepted, nor does *Bruder* admit a feminine derivation c) words like *Schlampe* "bitch" may be unisex (hence my reference) but, theoretically, *-r* derivation from the verb is plausible (actually diminutive *Schlampi* may be more common). Which shows, in essence, that the root is semantically underspecified.

Comment: As for *wido-wer* as in *were-wolf*, the assumption that *widower* derived from f. *widow* is likely incorrect. The root seems to be m. *\*-wós* ~ f. *-\*weh₂* in zerograde *\*-wh₂*, with rhotacism in the male paradigm possibly before reinterpretation.

Answer (score 4):

### Manambu

Manambu, native to northern Papua New Guinea, is such a language since the unmarked form is used for females and a suffix is added when referring to males  ("-də" or "-d"). A feminine suffix, "-l" does exist, but it's only used in certain contexts, using the rules in Table 5.2 of [The Manambu Language of East Sepik, Papua New Guinea](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Manambu_Language_of_East_Sepik_Papua/). Unlike English, the suffix isn't attached to the noun it refers to:

> The language has two genders, masculine and feminine. Gender is covert: it cannot be inferred from the form of the noun. One knows what gender a noun belongs to by the form of an agreeing demonstrative, adjective, possessive pronoun, or verb.
>
> —[How Gender Shapes the World](https://www.google.com/books/edition/How_Gender_Shapes_the_World/21asDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=%22d%C9%99%22%20%22Manambu%22) (HGStW)

It is a system of grammatical gender proper. In contexts where English would use "it" (small children, animals of unknown sex, and objects), Manambu assigns a gender based on shape, size, or some other factors. HGStW says "[c]hoice of gender for humans is always based on their Natural Gender, or sex" but notes there are exceptions, the primary one being that you can reverse the gender as a joke (e.g., masculine to refer to a tall and slender woman).

The article [Wo- and Manambu: The Gender of Things in Manambu](https://languageswithwilf.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/wo-and-manambu-the-gender-of-things-in-manambu/) gives examples with "wuna" ("my" for feminine) and "wunadə" ("my" for masculine):

> - ñaməs = younger sibling
>
>   - wuna ñaməs = my younger sister
>   - wunadə ñaməs = my younger brother
> - maam = older sibling
>
>   - wuna maam = my older sister
>   - wunadə maam = my older brother

Based on another example featuring adjectives, I would assume that "rakrak ñaməs" would be a grammatical way to refer to "the happy older sister" and "rakrakdə ñaməs" to "the happy older brother".

I found another example in [The division of GENDER](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358851910_The_division_of_GENDER) (quoting Aikhenvald 2012):

"This big man stays in the house":

| ke-də | numa-də | du | wiya:m | kwa-na-d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| this-M.SG | big-M.SG | man | house.LOC | stay-PRES-M.SG |

"This big woman stays in the house":

| ka-∅ | numa-∅ | ta:kw | wiya:m | kwa-na-∅ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| this-F.SG | big-F.SG | woman | house.LOC | stay-PRES-F.SG |

Answer (score 3):

German has such kind of derivation, but only marginally, for some animals where the default is female and the male form is marked. Examples include

- *Ente, Enterich* or *Erpel* "duck"
- *Gans, Ganter* or *Gänserich* "goose"
- *Katze, Kater* "cat"
- *Ziege, Ziegenbock* "goat"

Some animals are neuter by default and have marked males, e.g.,

- *Reh, Rehbock* "roe"

But this hardly meets the requirement of regularity, although we see the recurring (pseudo-)suffixes *-erich* for birds and *-bock* for ungulates.

Comment: It sounds like the situation is somewhat similar to English in that it doesn't really happen. Can you label the examples and add the etymology for people without knowledge of German? It's a bit suspicious to see words that are etymologically connected to both "drake" and "gander" when in [my linked answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/421783/191178) I discarded those words because of the OED. Also, it's not clear to me if "Katze/Kater" is an example or are [from a common neutral(?) origin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/kattuz).

Comment: Are these defaults actually females (rather than just feminines)? German Wiktionary at least lists the generic sense describing the species before listing the specific sense describing the female of that species (if at all). I would argue that they are species designators that have specifically male (and masculine) counterparts, but which are not in themselves words for females. @Laurel What does the OED say that made you discard them? _Gander_ is formed with the same masculising suffix (PG _*-zō_) as _Kater_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet See [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64931895#64931895)—it's possible that I made a mistake. However, the fact that we have to have this conversation at all makes me think it's not really what I'm looking for, since it looks like it was *never* regular. I get the feeling that adding these suffixes to other female words would have sounded as unidiomatic as "doe-buck" does in English.

Comment: This is the general *-er* derivation, which I remarked in comments. *Kätzer* was likely avoided and replaced by a Low German form. *Ziege* "tig" is uncertain in origin and in view of semantics maybe influenced by *Zofe* (MHG "zoffen, zaffen ‘zögern’", DWDS), compare *Meckerziege*. Since *Geiß* alone means "he-goat" eg *Geißbock* shows that *-bock* does not specify gender but virility, same as *Ochse* "ox" vs. *Zuchtbulle* "taurus potens". The *-ch* ending of *Enterich* and *Gänserich* is in origin probably neuter diminutive *-ch-en*, not sure; certainly not generally valid. Maybe *-rex* "king"

Comment: [p.s.] or rebracketed from something like *drake*, German *Drachen*.

Comment: @vectory At least in my dialect it is *die Geiß* and it is generally understood as a female (that gives milk, aptly termed *Bergmannskuh* "miners cow").

Comment: [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Geisz) confirms my intuition about *dieGeiß*.

Comment: Oh shoot, you are right. Old High German *geiz* is unisex though mostly irrelevant when no such early evidence of the compound exists.